# How to use google fonts in a typescript react-app with JSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, jss

How do I include Google [fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) so I can use them in my JSS?

```
const styles = ({palette, typography}: Theme) => 
  createStyles({
    time: {
      flexBasis: '10%',
      flexShrink: 0,
      fontSize: typography.pxToRem(20)
    },
    guestname: {
      flexBasis: '20%',
      flexShrink: 0,
      fontSize: typography.pxToRem(20),
    }
})
```

Comment: Check out the [Getting Started guide](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go on fonts.google.com, "select the font(s)" you need. When you are finished, click the `@import` tab and copy the `@import` code only:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
```

paste it in your CSS file, e.g. `index.css`
 then save.

In your JSS, to use the imported font, do:

```
const styles = ({palette, typography}: Theme) => 
  createStyles({
    time: {
      flexBasis: '10%',
      flexShrink: 0,
      fontFamily: "'Montserrat', sans-serif", // <-- FONT IS USED HERE
      fontSize: typography.pxToRem(20)
    },
    guestname: {
      flexBasis: '20%',
      flexShrink: 0,
      fontSize: typography.pxToRem(20),
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Google fonts with JSS

Add in your css file i.e, app.css, style.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans');
```

Please change URL of your font that you want use, else working fine

and use this as :

```
{
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', cursive;
}
```